# Add disabled to form option that are on the table list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a table and a form with a dropdown:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="text">Apple</td>
        <td class="name">John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text">Orange</td>
        <td class="name">Smith</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form>
    <select>
        <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="Grape">Grape</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and I want to add a disabled attribute to every option on the dropdown that is already on the table resulting in this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="text">Apple</td>
        <td class="name">John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="text">Orange</td>
        <td class="name">Smith</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form>
    <select>
        <option value="Apple" disabled>Apple</option>
        <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
        <option value="Orange" disabled>Orange</option>
        <option value="Grape">Grape</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Is there any way to achieve using jQuery?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qm82Z/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("td.text").text(function(i, txt) {
    $("select option[value='" + $.trim(txt) + "']").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/322PA/

Answer (score 0):

Get each item value from the select option and compare it with the data inside table row. If both matches then disable the data/option in dropdownlist/select element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //loop through the select option
    $("form > select").children().each(function(){
        //store each option to check later
        var item = $(this).val();
        //loop through table row
        $("table").children().each(function(){
            //loop through table data
            $("tr").children().each(function(){
                //compare previously stored item with table data value
                if(item == $(this).text()){
                    //disable option 
                    $("form > select > option:contains(" + item + ")").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/HTvVp/)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you will be dynamically changing the content of the table and want the select element to update when the table changes. You must therefore make sure it updates each time it's used.

```
$("#theSelector").bind("mouseenter", disableOptions);

function disableOptions() {

    var tableData = [];
        $("#theTable tr").each(function() {
            tableData.push($(this).children(":first").text());
        });

    $("#theSelector option").each(
        function() {
            if(jQuery.inArray(this.text, tableData) > -1) {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    );
}
```